# Why are some questions shaded green?

Tags: support, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some questions on the question page darker than others?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/why-are-some-questions-on-the-question-page-darker-than-others)

I've really tried to figure this one out on my own, but I give up. What determines  whether or not a question is shaded with a green-tint background on the ALL QUESTIONS pages? I'm just hoping it's not something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question is shaded green if one of its tags is in your "Favorite Tags" list on the right column of the page.

Answer (score 6):

This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer a tag for you.

You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in [your profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5822/Callithumpian?tab=prefs).  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.

If the system is inferring a favorite tag for you and you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorns-eating-waffles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns-eating-waffles)? (:

Comment: Thanks for the additional helpful information.