# Love seeing questions highlighted... but what is it?

Tags: support

I just wanted to give mad props for highlighting questions I've already voted on in the Questions page.

EDIT: I've noticed that I didn't quite get this right.  Exactly what causes a question to be highlighted?

Comment: Of course, now that I've mentioned it, it disappears... maybe someone's fiddling with stuff.

Comment: Good to see someone else had the same question. I couldn't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some questions shaded green?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/why-are-some-questions-shaded-green)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called "Frequented Tags" and it is automatically inferred based on your question browsing statistics.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=frequented+tags

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of [favorite tags](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/why-are-some-questions-shaded-green), whether you set them manually or they are automatically chosen by the system.

Comment: They don't look green to me though (more of just a darker brown background color) so I'm kind of guessing that it's the same thing under discussion. I'm not even colorblind...

Comment: Yeah, it's the same thing I was asking about. I should have said _darker brown with a slight greenish tint_ perhaps (at least on my screen).