# Why are some questions surrounded by a cream-coloured rectangular box?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Love seeing questions highlighted… but what is it?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/love-seeing-questions-highlighted-but-what-is-it)
>   [Why are some questions shaded green?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/why-are-some-questions-shaded-green)

Some questions are surrounded by a cream-coloured (darker than the website's background colour) box like this:[image]

It started happening recently. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "Frequented Tags" thing:

[image]

It cannot be changed, *unless* you set some tag preferences. If you add at least one favourite tag, then this will disappear.
If you don't want to see the box at all, try choosing a really obscure tag. I suggest using [iiuiuhijbwajhefb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iiuiuhijbwajhefb). Or, if you want an actual tag, something like [isograms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isograms) will work.

Comment: I did not know that! I'm gonna delete my answer, if you want to poach anything from it before it's gone.

Comment: @MattЭллен Go ahead and delete it, I'll just snag the picture from you.