# Why are some questions on the question page darker than others?

Tags: support, design, style

I've noticed some questions on the questions page are tinted darker than others

[image]

Looking at the CSS, I see that they have the same class applied to them as the normal-shaded questions on the page (and the other tinted ones). Is this a bug, or does it serve some design purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some questions shaded green?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/why-are-some-questions-shaded-green)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The darker colored questions are those questions which have a tag that is one of your **Favorite Tags**. You can define these Favorite Tags on the right side of the home page:

[image: Favorite Tags options]

If I recall correctly, SE now automagically tries to identify your Favorite Tags if you never specified any by analyzing your browsing patterns. A quick search seems to imply that these are called [Frequented tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108224/documentation-for-frequented-tags-feature).

Also, Ignored Tag questions should get a slight fade out effect.